# When were the names of Mishna Tractates set?

Tags: halacha-theory, talmud-bavli

When were the names of the 60 Tractates and 6 Sdarim set? ([WIKI here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talmud#Mishnah)).

Comment: Were they ever 'codified'? Some Rishonim refer to Zevachim as Shechitat Kodshim, and some refer to Beitzah as Yom Tov.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

*Turns out the answer was closer than I thought.*

Rambam in his [Preface to Mishnah](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rambam_Introduction_to_the_Mishnah.15.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi), chapter 15, writes explicitly that Rebbi made up the names of the Sdarim and the Traktates. Rambam also gives an explanation for why Rebbi ordered the Sdarim and Tractates in such a way.

> "וכאשר חשב המחבר לחבר זה הספר על זאת התכונה ראה לחלק אותו לששה חלקים:
> החלק הראשון במצות המחויבות בצמח הארץ כמו כלאים שמטה וערלה ותרומות ומעשרות ושאר חקי המתנות:
> והחלק השני בפרקי זמני השנה והמועדים ומה שנתחייב בהם והשתנות משפטיהם והאסור בהם והמותר ומה שנכון לחבר בכל פרק מהם מן הדינים והמצות:
> והחלק השלישי בבעילות וההפרש שיש בדינין בין האנשים והנשים כגון היבום והחליצה והכתובה וקדושין וגיטין ומה שהוא ראוי לומר בכל פרק מהם:
> והחלק הרביעי בדינין ובמריבות שבין אדם לחבירו ובסתורות ובמשא ובמתן ובשותפות הקרקעות והדומה לו:"
> והחלק החמישי בעניני הקרבנות כפי השתנות משפטיהם ורוב עניניהם:
> והחלק הששי בענין טהרות והפכם.
>
> **"וקרא כל חלק מהם סדר. החלק הראשון נקרא סדר זרעים. והשני סדר מועד. והשלישי סדר נשים. והרביעי סדר נזיקין. והחמישי סדר קדשים. והששי סדר טהרות. (והסימן זמ"ן נק"ט). "**
>
> And he called each of its divisions, Order – [such that] the first division is the Order of Seeds (Zeraim); the second is the Order of Appointed Time (Moed); the third is the Order of Women (Nashim); the fourth is the Order of Damages (Nezikin); the fifth is the Order of Holy Things (Kodashim); and the sixth is the Order of Purities (Tahorot). (And their mnemonic is Zema"n Naka"t ).

*(Thanks to mbloch for the link).*

Comment: Where does this quote talk about naming the tractates?