# When was the Mishnah penned?

Tags: mishna, oral-torah

According to [this](https://thegemara.com/the-epistle-of-sherira-gaon-a-point-of-departure-for-the-academic-study-of-the-mishnah/#fn-237-3), the French Iggeret of Rav Sherira Gaon is considered more authentic. Based on this premise, the Mishnah was not written down by Rabbi Judah but continued to be transmitted orally.

So my question is, when was the Mishnah finally penned and by whom?

Comment: There are two conflicting traditions.I remember having seen something here on MY, but I can't find it.

Comment: @Kazibácsi I'm aware there are conflicting traditions. However, based on the premise in the OP (that the Mishnah was not penned, rather it continued orally), who finally penned the Mishnah and when?

Comment: I'm not talking about the two traditions of the Igeret. There's an Ashkenazi tradition supported by Rashi among others, and there's an Sefardi/Mizrachi based on Rambam.

Comment: I think we all see the book of Mishnah proofread, signed, published, distributed through all diaspora, and put on every shul's shelves just like we do. Wrong. Pieces by pieces Mishnayos were copied chapter by chapter and sometimes Mishnah by Mishnah without any order for centuries. IMO, the Mishnah is *attributed* to Rebbi, not really penned, compiled, or signed by.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/109880/why-didnt-rebbi-compile-everything-that-was-known-in-the-mishnah?r=SearchResults&s=2|6.8062

Comment: Very related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60565/what-was-rabbi-yehuda-hanassis-role-in-compiling-the-mishnah/95644?r=SearchResults&s=17|6.0475#95644

Answer (score 1):

In [Maharat's Hayes, Introduction To Talmud](https://www.sefaria.org/Mevo_HaTalmud_(Chajes).33.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> **עוד האריכו המחברים להוכיח בראיות שונות, דרבי סידר המשנה בששה סדרים, אבל לא נכתבה המשנה בזמנו על ספר, רק היתה שנויה בעל פה לפי סדר של רבי**, והארכתי בזה בספרי תורת נביאים, ועתה ראיתי להרב מוה׳ יעקב חאגיז בספרו התחלת חכמה, הקדמה בדרכי המשנה, החליט ג״כ כזאת והביא הראי׳ שהזכרתי מן ש״ס (עירובין ס״ב ע״ב) כגון מגילת תענית דכתיבא ומנחא, וכ׳ רש״י ז״ל להכי נקט מגילת תענית לפי שלא היתה דבר הלכה כתובה בימיהם אפי׳ אות אחת חוץ ממגילת תענית ע״ש, הרי דבימי האמוראים בזמן אביי ור׳ יעקב בר אבא לא היתה המשנה בכתב עדיין וע״כ בדבריו מוכח מן הסוגיא, דאל״ה למה לא נקטו כגון המשנה דכתיבא ומנחא, וע׳ רש״י (ב״מ ל״ג ע״א) דכתב המשנה וגמרא דורות אחרונות כתבוהו ע״ש, ועד ימיו של רבינו הקדוש לא הי׳ מסודרות רק קצת מסכתות, כמו מס׳ כלים, ומסכת מדות, ועדיות, ותמיד. ועוד איזהו פרקים שונים, ואולם רבי אסף וקבץ וסדר כל המשניות בסדר אחד, וסתמה אליבא דר׳ עקיבא ור׳ מאיר, ופעמים שנראה לו דברי היחיד, שנאה בלשון רבים: עוד הביאו ראי׳ מה שמצינו דרב ושמואל פליגי אם מעברין תנן, או מאברין, (עירובין נ״ג ע״א), וכן החכמים מסופקים אם אדיהן תנן או עדיהן (ע״ז ב׳ ע״א) וכדומה עוד הרבה ואם הי׳ משניות בכתב,. הרי יכולין לעיין היכי כתיבי, וכה״ג פריך הש״ס (קידושין ל׳ ע״א) ניתי ספר תורה ונחזי: עוד הביאו ראי׳ מה דכ׳ רש״י (ב״מ ל״ג ע״א) הדר דריש הוי רץ למשנה, שירא פן ישתכחו המשניות ויחליפו שמות החכמים, ובמקום אסור יאמרו מותר עכ״ל, ואם הי׳ המשניות כתובות על ספר, לא שייך לטעות: עוד מצינו חילוק בין גירסות המשניות הקבועות בתלמוד בבלי, לגירסות המשניות הקבועות בתלמוד בירושלמי, כמו במשנה פ״ט דשביעית ופ״ה דתרומות (לא יכולתי להלום דברי הרב ר״י חאגיז, ולא מצאתי שם חילוק בגירסות), ואנכי מצאתי בסוטה ר״פ אלו נאמרין דבבבלי הגירסא נאמרים בכל לשון, ובירושלמי הגי׳ נאמרים בלשונם, ואם כ׳ רבי המשניות ניתי ספר ונחזה, אבל מאחר שהי׳ האמוראים לומדים המשניות בעל פה החליפו:

So he says that the Mishna was written down after Rabbi and even after the Gmara. He brings several proofs, one being the Gmara :

> אֲמַר לֵיהּ רַבִּי יַעֲקֹב בַּר אַבָּא לְאַבָּיֵי: כְּגוֹן מְגִלַּת תַּעֲנִית דִּכְתִיבָא וּמַנְּחָא.

> Rabbi Ya’akov bar Abba said to Abaye: With regard to matters such as those detailed in Megillat Ta’anit, which is written and laid on the shelf

Why didn't the Talmud just speak about the Mishna ? Because it wasn't written then.

Comment: So when was it written, and by whom?

Comment: So how do you interpret the words of the [Rambam](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/901656/jewish/Introduction-to-Mishneh-Torah.htm): _He_ (i.e. Yehudah haNasi) _taught it to the Sages in public and revealed it to the Jewish people, who all wrote it down. They spread it in all places so that the Oral Law would not be forgotten by the Jewish people._